# Equivalent R Language for Python Pandas Slice

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas

I have some code in Python Pandas that I would like to find the similar code in R.

```
data

Time
-0.3350   -0.023798
-0.3345   -0.019036
-0.3340   -0.010623
-0.3335   -0.001733
-0.3330    0.345787
Name: Pressure, dtype: float64
```

Using the data above, if I want all the rows up to and including -0.010623 I simply write:

```
data[:-0.010623]
```

My question is in R how do I write this.  I have tried the following:

```
tail(data$Pressure, -0.010623)
```

But it does not work.

Comment: I do not think in panads you can using data[:-0.010623] to get what you described

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such terse operation in R that I'm aware of.  Try this:

```
data[seq_len(which(data$Pressure == -0.010623)),]

     Time Pressure
1 -0.3350 -0.02380
2 -0.3345 -0.01904
3 -0.3340 -0.01062
```

Data:

```
data <- read.table(textConnection(
"Time   Pressure
-0.3350   -0.023798
-0.3345   -0.019036
-0.3340   -0.010623
-0.3335   -0.001733
-0.3330    0.345787"
), header=T)
```

Comment: I've tested your code on the mtcars dataset and it works, but I'm getting a warning.  

    `mtcars[seq_len(which(mtcars$mpg == 21.4)),]

    Warning message in seq_len(which(mtcars$mpg == 21.4)):
    “first element used of 'length.out' argument”`

The output from mtcars is as expected and shows all the data above the mpg 21.4.

Comment: The warning is due to there are two rows with mpg 21.4.  You can just ignore it, or you can pass the first element only, e.g., `mtcars[seq_len(which(mtcars$mpg == 21.4)[1]),]`